# Media & Device object or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, wpf, ip-camera, onvif

I am fairly new to c# and am trying to write a basic program to stream video via an Onvif camera device. I am able to mostly follow and understand [this 8 min tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk6vAyIZZ0A&list=PLc2UaWzFQrPN7XNq2mAkVdsMkRCI0BMML&index=2).

But a few things I can't figure out. Even after adding the Vlc references, and the two Onvif service reference there are a few pieces of the code that wont compile. The tutorial is difficult to follow because he skips major steps. I am trying to identify what `Device` & `Media` & `EndPointAddress` represent in the following code (per his tutorial).

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   UriBuilder deviceUri;
   Media.Media2Client media;
   Media.MediaProfile[] profiles;

   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }


   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //Constructor for the custom Uri requires the onvif service address. 
      deviceUri = new UriBuilder("http:/onvif/device_service");

      //Sting manipulation: Need to check if our address contains a port. (Input validation)
      string[] addr = Adress.Text.Split(':');

      deviceUri.Host = addr[0];

      if (addr.Length == 2)
         deviceUri.Port = Convert.ToInt16(addr[1]);

      System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding;
      HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
      httpTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
      binding = new CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8), httpTransport);

      Device.DeviceClient device = new Device.DeviceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(deviceUri.ToString()));
      Device.Service[] services = device.GetServices(false);

      Device.Service xmedia = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Namespace == "http://www.onvif.org/ver20.media/wsdl");

      if (xmedia != null)
      {
         media = new Media.Media2Client(binding, new EndPointAddress(deviceUri.ToString()));
         media.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ToString.ClientCredential.UserName = Login.Text;
         media.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ToString.ClientCredential.UserName = Login.Text;
         media.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpresonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

         profiles = media.GetProfiles(null, null);
         if (profiles != null)
            foreach (var p in profiles)
               listBox1.Items.Add(p.Name);

      }

      listBox1.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
      video.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryneeded += MediaPlayer_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded;
      video.MediaPlayer.EndInit();


   }

   private void MediaPlayer_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcLibDirectoryNeededEventArgs e)
   {
      if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
      {
         e.VlcLibDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC");
      }
   }

   private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (profiles != null && listBox1.SelectedIndex >=)
      {
         UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(media.GetStreamUri("RtspOverHttp", profiles[listBox1.SelectedIndex].token));
         uri.Host = deviceUri.Host;
         uri.Port = deviceUri.Port;
         uri.Scheme = "rtsp";
         information.Text = uri.Path; ;
         string[] options = { ":rtsp-http", ":rtps-http-port=" + uri.Port, ":rtsp-user=" + Login.Text, ":rtsp-pwd=" + passwordBox.Password };

         video.MediaPlayer.Play(uri.Uri, options);

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Device` and `Media` are namespaces in your project with classes that are auto-generated from the web services that you have referenced. When you add a service reference via *References > Add Service Reference*, Visual Studio will create source code for a WCF client proxy from the WSDL metadata using the *WCF Web Service Reference* tool, so that can access that service.

WSDL or *Web Services Description Language* is an XML based language for describing the interface of web services, you can find the ones from the tutorial here:

- `Device` interface - See definition at https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl
- `Media` interface - See definition at https://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl/media.wsdl

The `EndpointAddress` class is located in the `System.ServiceModel` assembly, you probably got a typo there. However, there is also a NuGet package for it, called [`System.Private.ServiceModel`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Private.ServiceModel/), but you won't need that. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.endpointaddress?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) of `EndpointAddress`:

> Provides a unique network address that a client uses to communicate with a service endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for Answering! I have never used Service References before. I did add them as you say when i originally wrote the code but obviously something did not work correctly. Do we need to put them in the "included Libraries" at the top or should this be automatic? Any suggestions on how to get these Service References to work correctly?

Comment: @BDHys All you have to do is select _References > Add Service Reference_ in Visual Studio, put in the web service adress as above and set a namespace name like `Device`, where the classes should be generated in. Then everything is generated automatically (inside of the `Device` namespace in your project) and you can access  the classes like `DeviceClient` directly.

Comment: @thattguy  Thank you! Then i'll do some additional research because something is not working correctly. I did try adding it as a library. After this it said "Media" and Device" were valid, but then I received additional errors on things like "device client" from the line of code that is... Device.DeviceClient client =.

Comment: I was able to remove the Service Descriptions and then reapply them. Now they work. Not sure what happened the first time.